# Intercepting def in a block

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming

I have a method that needs to do a bit of sorcery on the attached block. A sample of such a block might be

```
myMethod do 

   somemethod x
   someother y
   def name(a,b)
     a+b
   end
end
```

the first two method calls (`somemethod x` and `someother y`) should just be executed as normal. However I'd like to intercept the method definition (as S-expression) without actually defining a new method. I can do this if I transform the entire block to S-expressions and then search through the AST. However then I need to figure out how to call the methods. A solution to either will do. That is either

- intercepting the definition, transform to S-expression (that Ruby2Ruby can understand)
- transform the block to S-expressions and find the method calls and execute these

**EDIT**
The AST I'm looking for is something similar to

```
[:defn,
 :name,
 [:args,:a,:b],
 [:call,
     [lvar,:a],
     :+
     [lvar,:b]]]
```

Comment: Can you say something more about the requirement. what you want with `name`?

Comment: @RubyLovely I've updated with a sample

Comment: It seems [`Module#method_added`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Module.html#method-i-method_added) callback might let you do what you want.

Comment: @dbenhur as far as I can see from the documentation that callback is called after the method have been added. That could potentially be fixed with undefine/remove however name clashing would be a concern and handling that would highten the complexity and method_added only provides the name of the method, so I'd have to dig up the implementation of the method (that does seem to be easy though)

Comment: Yeah, that's why I only offered the pointer and not an answer. Does seem like the hook could let you catch the definition then use the AST toolkit of ruby2ruby to modify and replace the method. The callback does execute before anything has an opportunity to invoke the method.

Comment: @dbenhur yeah the problem is not whether something can invoke it before the hook executes more the handling the case where the method has the same name as a method of the executing module. It's not only likely that this will happen but guaranteed (The gem is used to write the gem I'm working on)

Comment: Perhaps you can run the block with an anonymous Class/Module dupped from your intended target, hook, modify, and inject into the real target?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to be able to define a method within a code block passed to another method, but intercept that inner method definition so that it doesn't actually get defined but is instead converted to an S-expression? So you want it to behave almost as if it were commented out and some external process had come through the source code and parsed out the implementation into an S-expression?

Something like:

```
myMethod do 

   somemethod x
   someother y
   # def name(a,b)
   #   a+b
   # end
end
```

Where `somemethod` and `someother` still execute, the implementation of `name` is defined, but is ignored by the Ruby interpreter. Then you somehow want to capture this implementation as an S-expression. It obviously wouldn't be done like this, by commenting it out, but its a nice way for me to picture the behavior.

Well, the RubyParser gem might do what you want. It takes advantage of the ability to pass in a 'here document' as a string to a method, as in this example:

```
def x (str)
  str
end

x( <<-EOF )
this is
   a here
document
EOF

# => "this is\n   a here\ndocument\n"
```

Using RubyParser, you can do something like the following:

```
require 'ruby_parser'
require 'pp'

pp RubyParser.new.parse( <<-EOF )
def plus(x,y)
  x+y
end
EOF
# => s(:defn, :name, s(:args, :a, :b), s(:call, s(:lvar, :a), :+, s(:lvar, :b)))
```

It would be a trivial matter, then, to merge it with your desired code, like so:

```
require 'ruby_parser'

def myMethod
  x = yield
end

def somemethod( x )
  puts x
end

def someother( y )
  puts y
end

x = 'magic'
y = 'output'

sexp = myMethod do
  somemethod x
  someother y
  RubyParser.new.parse( <<-EOF )
  def name(a,b)
    a+b
  end
  EOF
end

pp sexp
name(1,2)
# magic
# output
# s(:defn, :name, s(:args, :a, :b), s(:call, s(:lvar, :a), :+, s(:lvar, :b)))
# NoMethodError: undefined local variable or method 'name' for main:Object
```

As you can see, the method definition is essentially just a string, and can be manipulated as such.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion however I already have a solution that works for strings like yours I need it to work with an actual block of code